# What is the difference between EM and EKF?

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation, kalman-filter

I am new to statistical estimation theory, and I have read about the [EM algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm). This algorithm alternates between estimating hidden states using estimated model parameters (the E-step), and using those estimated hidden states to estimate the model parameters (the M-step). To me that is like estimating the hidden states and the parameters together.

The [Extended Kalman Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Kalman_filter) (EKF) can also estimate states and parameters by augmenting the state vector with model parameters. What is the difference between the EM algorithm and EKF for jointly estimating states and parameters, and why might I choose one over the other?

Forgive my ignorance and thanks in advance.

Comment: EKF (or just the Kalman filter) estimates state and covariance, not parameters. You can actually use EKF for the E-step of EM. It does not relate to the M-step.
This is more or less in the definition.

Comment: EKF can be used for parameter estimation as well by augmenting the state vector with model parameters. I did a EKF parameter estimation once before

Comment: "By augmenting the state"- by treating the parameter as a state, no longer as a parameter. In particular, you have all the usual KF issues- strong nonlinearities are a problem, you need to find and store Jacobians, work with maybe big error covariance matrices, etc. Conversely, MLE (as in EM) is computationally heavy, and gives you a number for the parameter, not a distribution.

Comment: With your permission, I will edit the question to make it clearer what you are asking- please edit again if you feel I have not done it justice.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel. The question reads much better now.